# Hide orders based on order status in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, filter, woocommerce, wordpress-hook, wp-admin

I have created one custom order status named as "Hidden".

Now in woocommmerce orders admin panel, I want to hide all orders which have order status "Hidden".

Is there any hook or filter function available to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: form where you want to hide order? backend, user order list ??

Answer (score 0):

Please use below hook in your child theme function.php. I hope this hook will you to achieve your goal.

add_filter( 'parse_query', 'modify_filter_owner');

function modify_filter_owner( $query )

{
    global $typenow;

```
global $pagenow;

if($typenow == 'shop_order' ) 

{
    ////Custom filter text will come here
}
```

}